# Extending a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

Currently I am tidying up one of my projects by using the more *pythonic* way of dong things. Now I struggle extending a list by values from a dictionary that are lists.

```
my_dict = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [2, 3, 4], 'c': [4, 5, 6]}
criteria = ['a', 'c']
my_list = []
for c in criteria:
    my_list.extend(my_dict[c])
```

Results in `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` which is the sought for result, where as

```
my_list = []
my_list.extend(my_dict[c] for c in criteria)
```

Results in a nested list `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`. I can't quite find a reason why this is happening

Comment: Are you asking why this happens, or how to fix it? Did you check what ``my_dict[c] for c in criteria`` and ``list(my_dict[c] for c in criteria)`` actually is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work because it attempts to extend the list with the result of the generator comprehension, which is a list of lists:

```
>>> list(my_dict[c] for c in criteria)
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

This is because `my_dict[c]` is itself a list.

A more Pythonic way is to use a list comprehension:

```
my_dict = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [2, 3, 4], 'c': [4, 5, 6]}
criteria = ['a', 'c']
my_list = [item for k in criteria for item in my_dict[k]]
>>> my_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

This uses a nested loop to select the values from the dict by criteria and to flatten the lists that are those values.